# PSSession won't work in script

Tags: powershell

So I have a script that connects to a terminal server, and then connects to 3 Domain Controllers to look up user accounts. When I run it from a .ps1 script, it gives me an error that 2 of 3 DC's can't be reached, but the 3rd DC can be reached. However if I manually type out get-aduser info on the 2 failing DC's it does work. (I've copied and pasted the info so I know it's the same).

Here's the script -

```
###################### PS Session ###################################
Enter-PSSession -Name TS7
Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Server -Force

###################### Account Check ######################
$red = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Server server.com -Credential ($redcred)
$redusers = ($red | Where-Object{$_.name -eq $Name})
if ($redusers) {
               $emailbody=$emailbody.AppendLine("redrocket\$Name found - contact DME")
               write-host "RedRocket/$name found - updating email"
               }
else           {
                $emailbody=$emailbody.AppendLine("redrocket\$Name not found")
                write-host "RedRocket/$name NOT found - updating email"
               }
               }
```

Here's the error:

> Get-ADUser : Unable to contact the server. This may be because this
>   server does not exist, it is currently down, or it does not have the
>   Active Directory Web Services running.

Comment: `Enter-PSSession` does not change the server, where rest of the script invoked.

Comment: i'm not sure i understand what you mean by that. If you're talking about the 2nd hop, the wsman takes care of the double hop authorization. And like i said, there's 3 DC's it connects to. The 3rd DC (which uses the same 'get-aduser' code as this DC) works - it's just that this server doesn't unless i type the info manually.

Comment: `Enter-PSSession` change active `Runspace` for next interactive command prompt, it does not affect script, which already executing in current `Runspace`.

Comment: Is there a command that does change where the rest of the script is invoked?

Comment: You can use `Invoke-Command`, which allows you to specify, what you want to invoke on remote server.